# Magento: Custom attributes option's new value field

Tags: magento, custom-attributes

I want to add a custom field in **Attribute option** in **Manage Attribute Options** menu in admin. Like **value** column beside the position column in admin. I have attached an image.

What I have done ... (Magento 1.8)

1. created a new field in `eav_attribute_option` table named **value** after `sort_order` filed.
2. changed `magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\eav\attribute\options.phtml` this file to show the **Value** column beside the **Position** column.
3. changed `getOptionValues()` method in this file `magento\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Block\Adminhtml\Attribute\Edit\Options\Abstract.php` to get data for my custom **value** column from database and show in admin side. It shows the default value of db in admin form.

   But when I want to save from admin panel the data doesn’t save in db.

I've been trying to find the model or controller that actually handles writing into the database to make sure my new field saves too.

Any help would be appreciated.

(I'd post an image to make you understand, but I can't since I need 10 points to be able to do it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

Update: Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Entity/Attribute.php

in function: _saveOption(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)

change:

```
$sortOrder = !empty($option[’order’][$optionId]) ? $option[’order’][$optionId] : 0; 
if (!$intOptionId) { 
$data = array( 
‘attribute_id’ => $object->getId(), 
‘sort_order’ => $sortOrder, 
); 
$adapter->insert($optionTable, $data); 
$intOptionId = $adapter->lastInsertId($optionTable); 
} else { 
$data = array(’sort_order’ => $sortOrder); 
$where = array(’option_id =?’ => $intOptionId); 
$adapter->update($optionTable, $data, $where); 
}
```

for this:

```
$sortOrder = !empty($option[’order’][$optionId]) ? $option[’order’][$optionId] : 0; 
$yourAttribute = (isset($option[’your_attr_field’]) && !empty($option[’your_attr_field’][$optionId])) ? $option[’your_attr_field’][$optionId] : ‘’; 
if (!$intOptionId) { 
$data = array( 
‘attribute_id’ => $object->getId(), 
‘sort_order’ => $sortOrder, 
‘your_attr_field’ => $yourAttribute 
); 
$adapter->insert($optionTable, $data); 
$intOptionId = $adapter->lastInsertId($optionTable); 
} else { 
$data = array(’sort_order’ => $sortOrder, ‘your_attr_field’ => $yourAttribute); 
$where = array(’option_id =?’ => $intOptionId); 
$adapter->update($optionTable, $data, $where); 
}
```

I could use some help in making all this changes 'the Magento way'